# Communication between Jsp page and Database

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I'm learning to programming and I'm trying to create in a page a list of booking that a user has done.
In particular, I would like to recover all the bookings made by a user using his email
I have create a JSP page:

```
<body>
<%=session.getAttribute("Nome") +" "+ session.getAttribute("Cognome") + " "+ session.getAttribute("Email") %>
<br>

Prenotazioni Effettuate:

<%
try{
            String email=(String)session.getAttribute("Email");         

       // out.print("Hello "+n);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
       // out.println("driver loaded");
     Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel","root" ,"123456789");
      //  out.println("Connect");
      Statement  stmt =  con.createStatement();
      //    out.println("conncetion successfull");
        String query="";
        String emailp = "";
        String arrivdate = "";

    query="select * from reservation where email = "+email;
    ResultSet r = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (r.next())
    {   
    emailp = r.getString("email");
    arrivdate = r.getString("arrivalDate");
    %>
Email: <%= emailp %>

Arrival date: <%= arrivdate %>


           <% }}

            catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
            out.close();

            %>
```

I don't understand why nothing is printed.
Is it a query problem or a code problem that's wrong? do you know how to help me?

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path
> [/Apartment] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
> java.io.IOException: Stream closed    at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:180)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
>   at
> org.apache.jsp.Prenotazionieffettuate_jsp._jspService(Prenotazionieffettuate_jsp.java:198)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What console error are you getting?

Comment: @SumeshTG GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Apartment] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Please include entire stacktrace in question.

Comment: @SumeshTG I have update my post

Comment: Check your jsp file is in proper structure?

Comment: Yes, my jsp file is WebContent

Comment: Do you have any servlet with `Apartment` this mapping.

Comment: Apartment is the name of the project, I don't have any servlet with this name

Comment: Do you have `web.xml`?

Comment: @SumeshTG Yes I have

Comment: By analyzing your code snippet you are not properly handled database connection and `out.close();` is used. what's the usage? It will close the output stream.

Comment: You're actually right about out.close (); ! What do you think about the connection to Database?

Comment: `con` is the connection varieble it should be closed when finishes every  database operation. Add a `finally` block to your `try-catch` close it `con.close()`. And you are trying to follow some bad programming. Try to learn MVC design pattern.

Comment: After catch I create finally method. 
If I use con.close() I receive an error about con: "con cannot be resolved"

Comment: Do you add MySQL library to the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I add MySQL Library

Comment: @SumeshTG I understand the error. If I Don't use WHERE email = "+email; it's work.. but I need to implement with the email. How can I do?

Comment: Infact if I tried to print my value  String email=(String)session.getAttribute("Email");
It's null!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved using this way:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE email= '" + session.getAttribute("Email") + "'";
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement instead! This opens up a lot of safety issues.